# How to set redirection page after successful login (WITHOUT Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

First, my loginInterceptor looks like this:

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginInterceptor.class);

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler) throws Exception{
        if (req.getSession().getAttribute("loginId") == null) {
            res.sendRedirect("signin");
            return false;
        }
    return true;
  }
}
```

This only redirects to sign in page if the user is not signed in. Now I want to redirect to a different page if someone successfully signs in, without using Spring Security. I first googled and it only showed me Spring Security but I need to do this without using Spring Security. I tried else statement but nothing new happened. Is there anything I can do to achieve what I want? Thanks in advance.

I'm using Spring MVC + Java.

Comment: show us your `else` code.

Comment: In the else statement I just added res.sendRedirect("otherpage"); return true. So I didn't feel the need to add that.

Comment: *This only redirects to sign in page if the user is not signed in.* What happens otherwise? The code above looks fine to me.

Comment: Oh I'm such an idiot. It looked like it didn't work because I was also redirecting in my controller too. I did that part weeks ago and totally forgot about that. But it was worth knowing about how true and false works in the  Spring interceptors, thanks to @ScaryWombat.

Answer (score 1):

As per the javadocs

> Returns: true if the execution chain should proceed with the next
>   interceptor or the handler itself. Else, DispatcherServlet assumes
>   that this interceptor has already dealt with the response itself.

So in you else code it should return `false`

Comment: You mean the console in Spring? There were no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Return true - "OK proceed"

Return false - "Stop proceeding" (Then you have to have a redirect, otherwise it will just stop I think)

If you need to redirect always from your `LoginInterceptor:preHandle` the try something like below

```
  public boolean preHandle(...){
        if (req.getSession().getAttribute("loginId") == null) {
            res.sendRedirect("signin");
        }else{
            res.sendRedirect("home");//You have already logged in
        }

     return false; //Spring stops interceptor channing
  }
```

There is a problem with above code which is it will always redirect to "home" for a logged in user even for a different URL pattern which intercept `LoginInterceptor` URL pattern.

I think your posted code is fine and there is something wrong somewhere else.